# NetSuite - see the list of all users

Tags: user-interface, netsuite

I have admin rights in NetSuite. I want to see the list of all users and edit some preferences for a user.

I am not able to locate my way in User Interface !!!

Where Can I see the list of All users to administrate??

Comment: I do not see a question.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main navigation menu: Setup > Users/Roles > Manage Users